# Open Semantic / Apache Solr indexing limit

Tags: solr

I have indexed a little over 5 million files with Open Semantic that uses Apache Solr.

I'm still indexing now and I don't get any error message during the indexing but I don't see the file count increase on the number of indexed files nor can I search those newly indexed documents.

Is there a limit to the number of documents that can be indexed? Is there a log where I could find error messages?

Thanks for your help!
Yoann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Solr shard (or core, if you using standalone mode) can hold 2B docs, so I am pretty sure you are ok regarding number of docs.

Logs can be seen in $SOLR_HOME/server/logs/solr.log, you should see additional rolling log files.

Maybe that tool does not commit till the end, and if no commit is done (explicit or by autocommit settings) no docs are seen yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Persimmonium! It used to commit frequently (I could see the number of indexed documents increase). I checked the log and the only thing that looks like an error is this: "2017-11-11T14:15:23.109+0000: 844039.439: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-11-11T14:15:23.109+0000: 844039.439: [Par$" There is also a mention about "  eden space 599232K, 100% used ". Any idea what this means? I'm wondering if a temp file is full. Disk has plenty of space (in both bytes and inodes.

Comment: that is just the jvm gc doing its thing, not an error.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have it installed on an EC2 instance. I created a snapshot of the EBS which unmounted one of them. After remounting it, it was able to add new files to the index. I have no idea what happened but it is fixed now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would also be helpful to check if you are maxing out on your Java heap. Check the solr admin console to get these details.